# CSS grid item set size of images

Tags: html, css

I have a grid container that I'm wanting to use to store 4 images per row. I'm trying to find a way to set the size of the images to a specific size. So if the original image is 900px by 500px, I want the CSS to set that size to 300px by 200px.

I've tried various different options that I've read, but none of them seem to be resizing the images. Can someone please tell me what I have wrong?

This is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <div class="row" v-if="othersImages">
      <div class="col" v-if="errors">
          <div class="alert alert-danger"><p>{{ errors }}</p></div>
      </div>
      <div id="others-images" class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-item" v-for="image in othersImages" :key="image.id">
              <picture v-bind="'image' + image.id">
                <img v-bind:src="image.image.path" v-bind:alt="image.description"/>
              </picture>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    min-width: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.grid-item{
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.picture > img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the `pictures` tag as a class in css? - `.picture`. Do it like this - `picture`. Full - `picture > img { ... }`. Look screen - https://ibb.co/grhPtKh.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was a mistake from me, making that change solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the html that you shared, picture is an html tag, but you have used the class syntax in css for it, which is causing the failure. Fixing the syntax should fix this issue.

```
picture > img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```